# Amount of possible events

Tags: probability

From the book Probability and Statistics for Computer Scientist, there is an example stated below:

> Consider a football game between the Dallas Cowboys and the New York
> Giants. The sample space consists of 3 outcomes,
>
> Ω = { Cowboys win, Giants win, they tie }
>
> Combining these outcomes in all possible ways, we obtain the following
> 2<sup>3</sup> = 8 events: Cowboys win, lose, tie, get at least a tie, get at most
> a tie, no tie, get some result, and get no result. The event “some
> result” is the entire sample space Ω, and by common sense, it should
> have probability 1. The event “no result” is empty, it does not
> contain any outcomes, so its probability is 0.

I don't get the part where the author list the possible ways from the outcomes. In my opinion, it should be:

- Cowboys lose, Giant lose and no tie { 0, 0, 0 }
- Cowboys win { 1, 0, 0 }
- Giant win { 0, 1, 0 }
- Cowboys and Giants has a tie { 0, 0, 1 }
- Giants win and has a tie { 0, 1 ,1 }
- Cowboys win and has a tie { 1, 0, 1}
- Cowboys win and Giants win { 1, 1, 0}
- Cowboys win, Giants win and has a tie { 1, 1, 1}

I am coming out with this hypothesis from another proof in the book.

> A sample space of N possible outcomes yields 2<sup>N</sup> possible events.
>
> Proof: To count all possible events, we shall see how many ways an
> event can be constructed. The first outcome can be included into our
> event or excluded, so there are two possibilities. Then, every next
> outcome is either included or excluded, so every time the number of
> possibilities doubles.

Please enlighten me. Thanks.

Comment: This is a trick question, as there is no scenario in which the Giants win.

Comment: More seriously:  the author is just saying that, given $N$ possible events we can ask, in turn, whether a given event occurs or not.  That's $N$ binary choices, hence $2^N$.  Of course some of the events might be mutually exclusive, in which case the "combined event" would have probability $0$. The author is fine with that.

Comment: "tie, get at least a tie, get at most a tie..." - I don't understand on the statement of at least and at most in this context.

Comment: Don't think about actual game rules, just think about events.  If the core events are $A,B,C$ then you can speak about "$C$ only", "$C$ but $A,B$ might have occurred as well", and "$A,B$ did not occur, but $C$ might have".  Again, the author doesn't care if some of these are logically inconsistent in a given situation.  All that means is that the event in question has probability $0$.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not a fan of the way this example was presented.  I'd have said that the three original events in $\Omega$ were already mutually exclusive and exhaustive so I'd have stopped there.  In other contexts, of course, the three events would not be mutually exclusive.

Comment: I agreed. Thank you very much for the guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For brevity, write the outcomes as $c$, $g$, and $t$. To say "the sample space consists of these three outcomes" means $\Omega$ is the set with three elements: $\Omega=\{c, g, t\}$. According to the excerpt that you highlighted, there are $2^3=8$ distinct events that can be described. The example is simply enumerating all the $8$ possible subsets of $\Omega$, and giving a description to each subset:

1. $\{c\}$ is the event that the **Cowboys win**.
2. $\{g\}$ is the event that the Giants win, i.e., the **Cowboys lose**.
3. $\{t\}$ is the event that the game ends in a **tie**.
4. $\{c, t\} = \{c\}\cup \{t\}$ means the Cowboys win, *or* the game ends in a tie. In brief, the **Cowboys get at least a tie**.
5. $\{g, t\} = \{g\}\cup \{t\}$ means the Giants win, *or* the game ends in a tie. In brief, the **Cowboys get at most a tie**.
6. $\{c, g\} = \{c\}\cup\{g\}$ means the Cowboys win, *or* the Giants win. The event can also be seen as $\{t\}^c$, so it is the complement of a tie, i.e., **no tie** occurred.
7. $\{c, g, t\}$ is the entire sample space, which can be described as **some result occurred**.
8. $\{\} =\emptyset$ is the empty set, which means **no result occurred**. If there are really only three possible outcomes, then this is impossible, which is what the empty set represents.

Comment: I still need your elaboration on the statement 4 and 5. In {c, t}, there is also probability that Cowboys win and there is no game ends in the tie. In this case, the Cowboys won't really entitled to get at least a tie right?

Comment: @MervynLee "At least a tie" means tie, or better. That's exactly what the event $\{c,t\}$ means. The event "Cowboys win, and the game does not end in a tie" is the same as the event $\{c\}$, which is a smaller event than $\{c,t\}$.

Comment: Owh. I get misunderstood by thinking it as - at least a tie = at least 1 or more ties. I got it now